# Dynamic number of elements in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to add labels one after another vertically and their number is dynamic. For now it works fine with this code:

```
let numUnitsLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
numUnitsLabel.text = units
numUnitsLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(28)
numUnitsLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
numUnitsLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
cell.contentView.addSubview(numUnitsLabel)

let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: numUnitsLabel, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 8 * CGFloat(i+1) + CGFloat(i*25) + CGFloat(i*20) - 5)
let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: numUnitsLabel, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -10)

cell.contentView.addConstraints([topConstraint, rightConstraint])
```

The cell is drawn fine. But when I add new item in the list and call `tableView.reloadData` the old labels are "remembered" and they are over new ones. The newly added object is put in the first place in the array and they are like one over another... Maybe my approach is bad, but if you have any suggestions please advice me.

Comment: You could subclass the tableviewcell and remove subviews in the prepareforreuse method.

Comment: Ok, but on a for cycle I have the code above, so basically I add the label X times. I subclassed prepareForReuse and now how to remove all of them?

Comment: If your labels are defined in the class, you could say numUnitsLabel.removeFromSuperview(). If you want to remove everything from the cell: 
for view in contentView {
  view.removeFromSuperview()
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that cells are re-used, so however a cell was prepared previously, it still has all of that state. In particular, its view hierarchy (added subviews) remain. The reason for this is generally a layout of a Table Cell stays the same, and only its *content* is meant to be re-set in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

You're using an anti-pattern, first of all, which is why you're running into difficulty.

If you really want to clear out and re-layout the cell, remove all subviews explicitly, every time, e.g.:

https://techfuzionwithsam.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-all-subviews-from-parent-viewsuper-view/

I suspect though, (admittedly this isn't CodeReview) that your design is flawed. Generally table cells don't need to grow in height with dynamic count of internal elements. You may need nested tables (!!), really just a single multi-line `UITextView` in each, or a table structured by sections with custom section header views.

Comment: Yes it worked with removing all cell.contentView's UIViews. But I know that the approach is bad, but at least this is the correct answer.